# Execute several js files with one button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Here's some HTML code I'm working on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="icon" href="icon/icon.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon/app.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/gamefont.css">
        <title>Game</title>
        <p>Game Resolution:</p>
<!-- <button onclick="runGame()">Run Game</button> -->
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="runGame()" />
 <select id="skill_category">
   <option value="resolution">Game Resolution</option>
 </select> 
   <select class="skill" id="resolution">
     <option value="1">1366x768</option>
     <option value="2">1600x900</option>
     <option value="3">1152x648</option>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!--
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/fpsmeter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/lz-string.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animarpg.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rungame.js"></script>
        -->
    </body>
    <script>
    function runGame() {
<script type="text/javascript">
function addScript("js/libs/pixi.js") {
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
js.src = JSfileName;
document.body.appendChild(js);
    };
    </script>
</html>
```

The problem is that I can't get the "clickme" button to execute `pixi.js` and the other scripts I have (which are commented out in the code.) through `node.js`. What went wrong?

Comment: You're mixing function declaration and function call. Should be `addScript("js/libs/pixi.js");` and `function addScript(JSfileName) { ... }`

Comment: @Arnauld Could you please post an answer with the fixes to make things more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pixiMidule = require('pixi');
```

note that i removed '. js'  from the require argument.

i hope you know how to use your already defined functions in pixi the nodejs way. if not, please check a bit about the nodejs module importing.

Comment: I'm using RPG Maker MV.

Answer (score 0):

it think it better to just create a sort of stack for including your javascript files in html. unless you are using frameworks like angular or any other framework that allows for dynamically importing external javascript files, i think u are still stuck on plain old html script tags. 
a rough solution would be to develop a kind of class that allows you load javascript on the required htm page using ajax. 
so that you could do something like

```
 var scriptData = ScriptLoader('pixi. js') ;
 var dynamicScript = document. createElement('script');
 dynamicScript.innerHTML = scriptData;
 document.body. appendChild(dynamicScript) ;
```